# uibutton.setTitle change text without changing font size

Tags: ios, swift

First, I added a button and set it's size to be 40

Then, in ViewController, I will change its text when user tap the button

```
startStopBtn.setTitle("START", for: .normal)
```

But not only the title change, the size also changed to 17.

Why is that? I want to keep the size unchanged.

Im using swift 5

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change your button **Style** from **Plain** to **Default**

Comment: omg it worked, whats the difference between plain and default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 15 introduced **Configuration** settings for many controls -- including `UIButton`.

When you create a button using Storyboard / Interface Builder in Xcode 13, the default configuration is `Plain`. Without changing that, you need to use the options via `UIButton.Configuration` to change much (most) of the button's appearance.

Selecting `Default` from the **Button Style** drop-down gives you a "pre-iOS 15" type of button.

Comment: is there any way we could figure out this ourselves from the code instead of documentation?

Comment: how to configure it programmatically? For example if I need to subclass a button and set this style inside.

Comment: @Gargo - not sure what you're asking?

Comment: @DonMag `class MyCustomButton: UIButton { ... }`, `let button = MyCustomButton()` and setting concrete configuration is hidden somewhere inside `MyCustomButton`

Comment: @Gargo - ok... you should probably post that as a new question... to difficult to understand here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+**. This works for all iOS versions.

```
extension UIButton {
    func setFont(_ font: UIFont) {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            self.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
                var outgoing = incoming
                outgoing.font = font
                return outgoing
            }
        }
        else {
            self.titleLabel?.font = font
        }
    }
}
```