# Change Button Title in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, ios15

I am using new button configuration style as introduce in iOS 15. It works great!

But when I try to change the title, **it is also change the font.**

Ref similar issue: [uibutton.setTitle change text without changing font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143374/uibutton-settitle-change-text-without-changing-font-size)

I don't want to go back to old style :(

My try:

```
var config = self?.btnNext.configuration
    config?.title = "New Title"
self?.btnNext.updateConfiguration()
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Try using an attributedTitle so you can set the font:

```
config?.attributedTitle = AttributedString("your new title", 
attributes: AttributeContainer([
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .black]))
```

Hope this helps.